# When does an active Ubuntu version expire?

Tags: lts, release-management

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

The EOL date for Trusty Tahr (14.04) is blank. When is End Of Life?

Comment: For LTS releases, it's 5 years after their release, some day in the same release month, so April 2019 for 14.04. Non-LTS releases are supported for 9 months instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ubuntu.com](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) has a graph on the current active releases + the lts releases.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's blank intentionally. If you check [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29), you'll see that EOL's **are** provided for each point release.

[image: EOL]